# Java, Jms, JPA, Oracle создать уникальные строки

Tags: java, jpa, jms

Надо брать данные из *Jms*  и искать в таблице *Address* если такой есть тогда взять его *ID* если нет создать новый и достать его *ID*. Вот код:

```
try{
   Query query = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT s.id FROM Address s WHERE s.counrtyId=?1 and s.districtId=?2 and s.regionId=?3  and s.city=upper(?4)")
                .setParameter(1, sa.getCounrtyId())
                .setParameter(2, sa.getDistrictId())
                .setParameter(3, sa.getRegionId())
                .setParameter(4, sa.getCity());

   Long result=(Long)query.getSingleResult();
   return result;
   } catch (NoResultException e){
        em.persist(entity);
        em.flush();
        return sa.getId();
  }
```

Так как *jms* обрабатывает сообщения параллельно он не находит в таблице такую строку создает новую  в транзакций пока вся обработка не закончится  только потом сохраняет. Если в параллельном потоке такая же строка он тоже в таблице ничего не находит и создает новую когда коммитит в базе появляются 2 таких строк.
Как можно предотвратить дублирование строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать в базе уникальный ключ по countryId, districtId, regionId, city (если это все поля, кроме id), тогда вместо вставки в базу дублирующей записи будет возникать исключение.
Если доставка сообщения jms осуществляется в транзакции, то она будет автоматически отменена и позже будет вторая попытка доставить это же сообщение. Со второй попытки id будет обнаружен.
Если доставка jms не окружена транзакцией, то можно отловить исключение вставки внутри метода, принимающего сообщение.
Ещё можно синхронизовать обработку сообщений, сделав её не параллельной, а поочерёдной, если такой вариант приемлем.

Comment: ID уникальный. У меня остальное содержимое строки дублируется. в следующем поиске у меня находит 2 строки с разными ID

Comment: На другие поля, точнее их комбинацию тоже можно наложить условие уникальности. Если нет причин хранить в таблице неотличимые копии адресов, то нужно сделать уникальный ключ по комбинации country, district, и т.д. Иначе только делать поочерёдную обработку.

Comment: @HELOWORD ну тут кроме поочерёдной обработки трудно что-либо предложить. Разве что ввести вместо null специальный "Неизвестный город"